# python variables in awk

Tags: python

I like python and I like awk too, and I know that can use it via subprocess or command library, BUT I want to use awk with variables defined before in     python, like this simple example:

```
file = 'file_i_want_read.list'

awk '{print $0}' file > another_file
```

anybody know how can I do it or something similar?

Comment: this has nothing to do with awk. You're asking how in python to define a variable to contain a file name which you'd then use when calling any shell command. You could replace "awk" with sed or grep or anything else and the answer would be the same. So, I'm going to remove the awk tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to not use the shell, and instead just pass a list of arguments to `subprocess`, so `file` is just one of those arguments.

The only trick is that if you don't use the shell, you can't use shell features like redirection; you have to use the equivalent `subprocess` features. Like this:

```
with open('another_file', 'wb') as output:
    subprocess.check_call(['awk', '{print $0}', file], stdout=output)
```

---

If you really want to use shell redirection instead, then you have to build a shell command line. That's mainly just a matter of using your favorite Python string manipulation methods. But you need to be careful to make sure to quote and/or escape things—e.g., if `file` might be `file i want read.list`, then that will show up as 4 separate arguments unless you put it in quotes. [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) can do that for you. So:

```
cmdline = "awk '{print $0}' %s > another_file" % (shlex.quote(file),)
subprocess.check_call(cmdline, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! both was pretty usefull :)